# Flutter "Bluetooth permission missing in manifest"

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth, android-permissions

i am trying to add bluetooth to my app to print vouchers

I am using `permission_handler: ^10.2.0`

android manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

I have tried multiple permissions and added and removed them many times

requesting permission

```
    Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> status = await [
      Permission.bluetoothConnect,
      Permission.bluetoothAdvertise,
      Permission.bluetooth,
      Permission.bluetoothScan,
    ].request();
    print(status);
```

I get this in the output

```
Bluetooth permission missing in manifest
I/flutter (13811): {Permission.bluetooth: PermissionStatus.denied, Permission.bluetoothScan: PermissionStatus.granted, Permission.bluetoothAdvertise: PermissionStatus.granted, Permission.bluetoothConnect: PermissionStatus.granted}
D/FlutterBluePlugin(13811): Connecting to 00:1B:35:11:2B:BA (id: 6)
I/flutter (13811): PlatformException(connect_error, UID 10339 / PID 13811 lacks permission android.permission.BLUETOOTH, java.lang.SecurityException: UID 10339 / PID 13811 lacks permission android.permission.BLUETOOTH
```

It says the bluetooth permission is missing from manifast, but it is added, i did
flutter clean, flutter pub upgrade and nothing seems to work

anyone can help me please

Comment: `permission_handler` is just check the permision. What package do you have to use the bluetooth function?

Comment: i used  ``` flutter_bluetooth_serial```

Answer (score -1):

### Update May 2023

#### tested on dart `3.0.1` and flutter `3.10.0`

Previously I used PR from Calm. and it works fine. but some how it throw me an error.

then i decided to change the repo. I think they are using different method.
for now i use from @bswhite1

```
 flutter_bluetooth_serial:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/bswhite1/flutter_bluetooth_serial.git
      ref: android_12_updates
```

> dont forget to `flutter clean` after change the dependencies

there are 3 option on PR :
https://github.com/edufolly/flutter_bluetooth_serial/pulls?q=android+12+

you may try which one is fits to your project.

---

#### old answer

this issue is occured after android 12. the version `0.4.0` only support for below android 12.

> I had test the package on android 10, and its work fine but for
> android 12 i got same issue.

developer who mantain the package `flutter_bluetooth_serial` not update the package for  the long time. Some issue raised on the repository. and some developer also raise the PR for the solution.

you can find some sugesstion on the github repo.
https://github.com/edufolly/flutter_bluetooth_serial/issues/161

and here one of my them that i use

changed your `pubspec.yaml`

- from this:

```
dependencies:
  flutter_bluetooth_serial: ^0.4.0
```

- to this:

```
 flutter_bluetooth_serial:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/calmh/flutter_bluetooth_serial.git
      ref: android12
```